# Want to uninstall components conditionally in NSIS script in Uninstall section

Tags: installation, nsis

I have written Installer and Updater using NSIS script for three different environments(QA,UAT and PROD). Installer is different for all three environments but updater is same. In my old installers uninstaller was not defined and newly updated installer has uninstaller code.
Now i want to modify my Updater in such way that it should create uninstaller for all environments which previously installed coz i don't want to run my new installers. I will be running only updated for now. I have written my uninstaller code in 'Section -post' using 'WriteUninstaller' see the code below. This code will add three entries to control panel programs list(SSCM). Now i am facing issue in my 'Section UnInstall' where i want to check which(QA or UAT or PROD) uninstaller is clicked by user from control panel.

How should i check which environment is clicked by user? Is it possible in NSIS scripts?

My Code:

```
!define PRODUCT_NAME "Updater name"
!define PRODUCT_NAME_QA "QA Name"
!define PRODUCT_NAME_UAT "UAT Name"
!define PRODUCT_NAME_PROD "PROD Name"
!define PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\App.exe"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY_QA "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME_QA}"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY_UAT "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME_UAT}"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY_PROD "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME_PROD}"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY "HKLM"

Section -Post
    IfFileExists "$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\QA\app.exe" QAExists PastQACheck
        QAExists:
                            WriteUninstaller "$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\QA\App Uninstall.exe"
                            WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" "" "$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\QA\App.exe"
                            WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY_QA}" \
                                       "DisplayName" "App (QA)"
                            WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY_QA}" \
                                       "UninstallString" "$\"$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\QA\App Uninstall.exe$\""
        PastQACheck:
    IfFileExists "$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\UAT\app.exe" UATExists PastUATCheck
        UATExists:
                            WriteUninstaller "$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\UAT\App Uninstall.exe"
                            WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" "" "$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\UAT\App.exe"
                            WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY_UAT}" \
                                       "DisplayName" "App (UAT)"
                            WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY_UAT}" \
                                       "UninstallString" "$\"$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\UAT\App Uninstall.exe$\""
        PastUATCheck:
    IfFileExists "$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\PROD\app.exe" PRODExists PastPRODCheck
        PRODExists:
                            WriteUninstaller "$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\PROD\App Uninstall.exe"
                            WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" "" "$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\PROD\App.exe"
                            WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY_PROD}" \
                                       "DisplayName" "App (PROD)"
                            WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY_PROD}" \
                                       "UninstallString" "$\"$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\PROD\App Uninstall.exe$\""
        PastQACheck:
SectionEnd

Section Uninstall
    SetShellVarContext all

    ;Check if uninstallation called for QA
    ;Condition to check if user has clicked QA uninstallation
        QAExists:
                            delete "$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\QA\"
                            delete  "$DESKTOP\QA.lnk"
                            RMDIR  "$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\QA\"

                            DeleteRegKey ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY_QA}"
                            DeleteRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}"
        PastQACheck:
    ;Check if uninstallation called for UAT
    ;Condition to check if user has clicked UAT uninstallation
        UATExists:
                            delete "$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\UAT\"
                            delete  "$DESKTOP\UAT.lnk"
                            RMDIR  "$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\UAT\"

                            DeleteRegKey ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY_UAT}"
                            DeleteRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}"
        PastUATCheck:
    ;Check if uninstallation called for PROD
    ;Condition to check if user has clicked PROD uninstallation
        PRODExists:
                            delete "$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\PROD\"
                            delete  "$DESKTOP\PROD.lnk"
                            RMDIR  "$PROGRAMFILES\App Path\PROD\"

                            DeleteRegKey ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY_PROD}"
                            DeleteRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}"
        PastPRODCheck:

   SetAutoClose true
 SectionEnd
```

What conditions to write to check environment for uninstallation?

Answer (score 0):

When you write the uninstaller you can also use `WriteINIStr` to write some extra identification data to a file in the same directory. You can then use something like `ReadINIStr $0 "$exedir\appuninstall.ini" "Data" "Id"` to read the data in the uninstaller.

It is also possible to append data to the end of the uninstaller itself:

```
Section
WriteUninstaller "$InstDir\Uninst.exe"
FileOpen $1 "$InstDir\Uninst.exe" a 
FileSeek $1 0 END 
FileWrite $1 "CUSTDATA:QA" ; special id
FileClose $1
SectionEnd

Function un.ReadCustomerData
# See http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ReadCustomerData
FunctionEnd

!include LogicLib.nsh
Section Uninstall
Push "CUSTDATA:"
Call un.ReadCustomerData
Pop $0
${If} $0 == "QA"
  DeleteRegKey ...
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```